# How to cleanly loop through subdirectories and recover their names in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

My projects is divided in three directories: data, scripts and results. The main pipeline is called from the directory on top of these three directories. data contains a series of subdirectories through which I want to loop, recover their names, and, to preserve the order, create new directories with the same name in results. I am doing so with the following script:

```
for d in data/*
   do 
   newname=$(echo $d | cut -f2 -d /)
   mkdir /results/$newname
   myprogram $d/raw_data > ../results/$newname/output
   done
```

which does the job, but I find clumsy having to cut the directory name and create an additional variable. Is there a more elegant way to do this? A way in which I can retrieve the name of the subdirectory in single step so I can do something like:

```
for d in (??????)
   do
   mkdir /Results/$d
   myprogram Data/$d/rawdata > results/$d/output
   done
```

**EDIT**
I just came about with this idea for the first line, which works quite well with the second piece of code

```
for d in $(ls -d  data/* | cut -f2 -d /)
```

Anybody has a better suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

That can be handled with prefix removal:

```
for d in data/*
do
   mkdir "./results/${d#*/}"
   myprogram "$d/raw_data" > "../results/${d#*/}/output"
done
```

The construct `${d#*/}` is called *prefix removal*.  It removes everything up to the first `/` in the string `$d`. As an example:

```
$ d=data/subdir1
$ echo "${d#*/}"
subdir1
```

#### Notes

1. Unless you want word splitting and pathname expansion, all shell variables should be in double-quotes.
2. `ls` was designed to produce human-friendly output.  As one example, a file name shown by `ls` are intended to display nicely and do not necessarily match the actual file name.  The use of `ls` in scripts should be avoided.
3. An alternative to *prefix removal* as shown above is the executable `dirname`.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ${parameter#word}
>  ${parameter##word}
>
> Remove  matching  prefix  pattern.   The  word  is expanded to produce
>   a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the
>   beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion
>   is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern
>   (the `#` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `##` case)
>   deleted.   If  parameter is  @ or *, the pattern removal operation is
>   applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ 
>   or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the
>   array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.